# Calculate differences between elements in group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Consider dataframe with exactly two rows per category in `a`:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"], "b": [1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 6]})
>   a   b
0   a   1
1   b   3
2   c   1
3   a   4
4   b   2
5   c   6
```

I want to calculate absolute differences between `b` per `a`:

```
    a   b
0   a   3
1   b   1
2   c   5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group them and then calculate the diff and abs (chain):

```
d.groupby('a').diff().abs().dropna()
```

The index might not be exactly as requested but this you can probably figure out.

Comment: I'm working with 800k rows dataset, and the method appeared to be very ineffective for me.

Comment: When you say ineffective, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: It took so much time, that I got bored of waiting and implemented another solution for my specific case, not the general one

Comment: Well if you found a faster way of achieving the same result it would be nice if you could share it with us.

Comment: Sure, but it's the different problem. I had 2 dataframes and had to compare one column. I've just merged them.

Comment: You inspired me to find another general solution for the problem. Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

Since each category in `a` has exactly 2 rows, the dataframe can be split into two like below:

```
first  = d.drop_duplicates("a", keep="first")
second = d.drop_duplicates("a", keep="last")
```

Then merge those and calculate the difference:

```
merged = first.merge(second, on="a")
(merged.b_x - merged.b_y).abs()
```

Comment: I actually thought about writing that this approach requires, that you have each value in 'a' only once.
I'm glad you solved the problem.